# How can I create a Button to download online pdf file?

Tags: android, android-button

```
 mWebView2 = new WebView(WEB2.this);
        mWebView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView2.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView2.goBack();
        mWebView2.goBackOrForward(20);
        mWebView2.setInitialScale(1);
        mWebView2.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView2.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);

        mWebView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView2.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.uobabylon.edu.iq/uobColeges/ad_downloads/4_25835_742.pdf");
        setContentView(mWebView2);
```

I would like to create a Button to download any online pdf file, and when click on this Button ot start the download.

I executed  this code to open pdf file , but i want to add a Button to download that pdf

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: I executed this code to open pdf .. but now i want to download this pdf

Comment: pdf file download is 100% same as any other file download. You just need to download a file. You can find couple of 1000s examples on the SO, and on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android application, on click of button open the url in the web browser using Intent. Like :

```
String url = "http://www.website.com/filename.pdf";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Once this code get executed it will automatically download the file in your device memory.

Comment: down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url="http://uobabylon.edu.iq/uobColeges/ad_downloads/4_25835_742.pdf";
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

see this accepted answer how to download file from url?[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

you not need webview to load file if you want just download and save it

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use this method it will ask to open your browser to download your file

```
       yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent download = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                String url = "YOUR FILE URL";
                download.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(download);
            }
        });
```

hope it helps you happy coding!